# OpenTok Archiving to Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: opentok, vonage

I know it's possible to link archiving to upload to Amazon S3 or Microsoft Azure after a call - is it possible to link it to Microsoft Teams or OneDrive? I'm unfamiliar with S3 storage solutions and so I've been a bit confused what is or isn't possible (as it mentions any S3-compatible storage is possible). If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Microsoft OneDrive is not supported as an OpenTok (Vonage Video API) archive destination. Microsoft Azure Storage, Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, and Cloudian are all supported ([see here](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/using-s3.html)).

It may be possible to download files from one of these storage platforms into your OneDrive. In general, OneDrive is a personal consumer-oriented platform rather than an enterprise-level secure storage platform with appropriate APIs and encrypted connections that OpenTok uses (listed above). I believe OneDrive as a consumer service may use Azure Storage underneath, so look to Microsoft for whether these can be easily connected.

Most of the storage platforms that are supported offer reasonable rates and get-started offers that may may it easy to try them out.

Lawrence, Vonage